# Primefaces dataTable inside dataList repeats active pagelinks with update

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Active pagelink update for all table. If you press page 2 in one table, then in another table, during the update, it will also go to page 2 
How to make PageLinks independent?

```
<h:form id="chatRes" class="chatRes">
    <p:dataList value="#{chatSession.providerChat}" var="chats" type="definition">
        <p:dataTable var="chat" value="#{chats.chats}" 
                            columns="#{chatSession.providerChat}" 
                            layout="grid"
                            rows="#{chatSession.pageSize}" 
                            rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
                            paginator="true"
                            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {PageLinks}">
            <p:column  ...
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:dataList>
    <p:poll interval="#{chatSession.POLL_TIME}" listener="#{chatSession.pollUpdate}" update="@(.chatRes)" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: Tried using the latest PrimeFaces version?

Comment: I use the latest version (6.2)

Comment: Tried 7.0RC3? Or latest snapshot?

Comment: 7.0RC3 mvnrepository not available. 7.0RC2 does not work